# Read csv file to create tasks that trigger from an event id using powershell and Task Scheduler COM-Object

Tags: powershell

I created a CSV File that looks like this

sequence,reportsource,reportname,reportid,fullpath

It contains several lines of configuration data for the scheduled tasks. I already figured out to use import-csv to get the content of the file. Now I want to loop through every line of the file and store all the values of the line to  variables - collection ($sequence,$reportsource,$reportname,$reportid,$fullpath), so I can create scheduled tasks with this values, but I don't know how to access the object, that import-csv provides. I need those values from the csv to hand over arguments to schtasks.exe to create my tasks.

```
$path = "C:\Workspace\macros\FullReportPathMR.csv"
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

$csv = Import-CSV -Path $path -Delimiter ";" | %{

##SCHTASKS /Create /TN $($_.reportname) /sc monthly /tr "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office###\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"
#New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" -Argument #"$($_.fullpath)"
#}

# The name of the scheduled task
[string]$TaskName = "$($_.reportsource) - $($_.reportname) - $($_.reportid)"
# The description of the task
[string]$TaskDescr = "Hello, it's you again! I am $($_.reportname) and I will get started, when Report ID $($_.reportid) is fired. Have a nice day!"
# The Task Action command
$TaskCommand0 = "kill.cmd"
$TaskCommand1 = "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE`""

# The Task Action command argument
$TaskArg = "hallelujah"
$TaskArg1 = "$($_.fullpath)"
# attach the Task Scheduler com object
$service = new-object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
# connect to the local machine. 
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381833(v=vs.85).aspx
$service.Connect()
$rootFolder = $service.GetFolder("\")

$TaskDefinition = $service.NewTask(0) 
$TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "$TaskDescr"
$TaskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = $true
$TaskDefinition.Settings.AllowDemandStart = $true

$triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
#http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383915(v=vs.85).aspx
$trigger = $triggers.Create(0) # Creates an "On an event" trigger
$trigger.Subscription = "<QueryList><Query Id='0'><Select Path='Application'>*[System[Provider[@Name='$($_.reportsource)'] and EventID='$($_.reportid)']]</Select></Query></QueryList>"

# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381841(v=vs.85).aspx
$Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
$action.Path = "$TaskCommand0"
$action.Arguments = "$TaskArg"
$Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
$action.Path = "$TaskCommand1"
$action.Arguments = "$TaskArg1"

#http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381365(v=vs.85).aspx
$rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("$TaskName",$TaskDefinition,6,"System",$null,5)

Write-Host $($_.sequence) $($_.reportsource) $($_.reportname) $($_.reportid) $($_.fullpath) "task created successfully."

}
```

CSV File Contains

```
sequence;reportsource;reportname;reportid;fullpath
1;Monthly Report;MR1;3;C:\Workspace\macros\1.txt
2;Monthly Report;MR2;6;C:\Workspace\macros\2.txt
3;Monthly Report;MR3;9;C:\Workspace\macros\3.txt
4;Monthly Report;MR4;12;C:\Workspace\macros\4.txt
```

https://www.verboon.info/2013/12/powershell-creating-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell-version-3/

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1028906-trigger-schedule-task-on-an-eventid

https://powershell.org/forums/topic/scheduled-task-with-multiple-actions/

The whole thing ran through on a Windows 7 with PS 2.0.-1.-1 administration machine and created 4 tasks with the desired parameters and arguments. The subscription - thing is a bit tricky, since I can't manipulate the event trigger using the GUI, just editing the XML. Every task provides 2 actions.

Comment: Please show some code. We can help you but only if we have something to go on.

Comment: I have no access to my code by now but the issue kept spinning in my head. I will provide asap :)

Comment: Please post edits into your post not in comments. This is for ease to read and other to help. Also please ether reply to my comment or the title post not to this comment as it belongs to Ortolar

Comment: Updated my post with working code for you

Comment: very nice, thank you

Comment: Dont reference a person in your post like @ArcSet. Instead thats a simple question that would be ok to ask in a comment. Also no the passing varable is from the pipe `|` this is `$_` If you create a pipe inside a foreach-object then you need to save the first $_ as a new varable. But i think thats a question for a new post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the question looks like it could just be simply

"How do I store the values of a CSV in a variable and loop through them?"

Lets go over some basic Powershell concepts to understand what you should be looking for.

The solution is.

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Test.csv" | %{
    Put Code Here
}
```

Ok lets explain this.

Lets image we have a csv called test.csv and the inside looks like

`"FirstName","LastName","Age"
"Bill","Boxer","52"
"Steve","Nix","21"`

When I call Import-CSV it creates a PSObject with properties that are equal to the header (First line of the CSV) :

```
(Import-csv "C:\Test.csv").FirstName
```

will return

`Bill
Steve`

In powershell we love piping **|** What this does is takes the information for the previous command and moves it to the next command using **$_** as the variable. We also love shorthand known as Alias.
Like `%{ Code Here }` is short hand for `foreach-object`

so

```
Import-csv "C:\Test.csv" | %{
    "My Name Is $($_.FirstName) $($_.LastName) and I am $($_.Age) years old"
}
```

Will get the data from the CSV and convert it to a PSObject. It will then Pipe **|** to a **Foreach-Object** aka **%{}** and then display the string :

`My Name Is Bill Boxer and I am 52 years old
My Name Is Steve Nix and I am 21 years old`

On a side note the $() inside the quotes is called a expression "$(Code here)" Allows you to output the code inside of a string

```
"Hello $_.FirstName"
```

Would show everything in the variable **$_** then add a .FirstName to the end of it like :

`@{FirstName=Bill; LastName=Boxer; Age=52}.FirstName`

But when you add the **$()** expression you are saying run this part as code.

```
"Hello $($_.FirstName)"
```

Shows

`Hello Bill`

So lets take a look at the code you posted in the comments 
(Please keep in mind to edit your post and post it there for other people to read.

Based on what I have posted above the issue is that your CSV isnt a CSV. CSV stands for Comma Separated Value. You have your values separated by Semi Colons.

You will need to define that in the Param for `import-Csv -Delimiter ";"`

A working script would be this :

```
$path = "C:\Workspace\macros\FullReportPathMR.csv"
Import-CSV -Path $path -Delimiter ";" | %{
    "$($_.sequence) $($_.reportsource) $($_.reportname) $($_.reportid) $($_.fullpath)"
}
```

output

`1 Monthly Report MR1 3 C:\Workspace\macros\1.txt
2 Monthly Report MR2 6 C:\Workspace\macros\2.txt
3 Monthly Report MR3 9 C:\Workspace\macros\3.txt
4 Monthly Report MR4 12 C:\Workspace\macros\4.txt`

Comment: hell yeah, the first time ever I get an output!! Nice! I needed to provide the delimiter, OK. So now I can hand over the "variables" to schtasks. But this I will do on Monday

Comment: please mark my answer as correct, Or upvote it. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer!! I already upvoted. If this thing does, what I am expecting, I will mark as answer. Thank you!!

Comment: OK, lets consider this: there is a loop, and with each iteration, another task is created using schtasks, where $($_.sequence) and the other variables contain the value I need. How can I make sure that the correct value is handed over to it, since there are 2 loops? I need to ensure that the index of the first loop (which holds the counting variable $i) references to the corresponding line of the csv?

Comment: I think you might need to open another question for that. This was about how to loop a single CSV. I would be glad to help you more but i need a new question with a example code. But just so you know this is powershell which if you read my whole post would points to the use of Piping and passing objects in pipes. the idea of [i] does not have a place in a foreach-object

Answer (score 0):

The code below will load a CSV where the code is located. 
Than it will loop inside of the file and create a schedule task.  
This script requires admin rights to create a new scheduled task and it will create a task as the current user.

```
# get scripth path location
$scriptpath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# import CSV
$csvdata = Import-Csv "$scriptpath\t.csv"

# this will clycle throught the data inside the object $csvdata
foreach ($result in $csvdata) {
    # to access the data just refer to object $result.[columns names inside CSV]

    # Build task info
    $action  = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$($result.fullpath)" -Argument 'case there is any argument'
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am 
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $($result.reportname) -Description $($result.reportname)
    # create the task scheduler
    New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 
}
```

The task creation part was base on: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/13/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/

Comment: Its awesome you are getting into powershell. But keep in mind that the solution here is vague and it seems the user cant do simple things like parse data in a CSV. Also looking at this script you should look more into piping |. Alot of these commands could be chained togather to make more effective and easier to read scripts.

Comment: But how does the powershell for $result know that it is a result? Where is it declared?

Comment: RWaternelon. It sounds like you are very new to scripting. You should take a read at the response i provided and then ask question from there. As for $Result thats a foreach statement which is iterateing over a psobject to get results one at a time.

Comment: @ortolar: thanks for your input, but it doesn't work using powershell commands. I will try to make it with schtasks.